# Display selected data from object if it matches with id javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var myData=[{id: 655, permissionType: "book", instructorControlled: "", batchId: -1, title: "PAckagebook1", …},{id: 643, permissionType: "book", instructorControlled: "", batchId: -1, title: "PR book", …}]
```

display data object seperately if it matches particular id.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use find method

```
var myData=[{id: 655, permissionType: "book", instructorControlled: "", batchId: -1, title: "PAckagebook1", …},{id: 643, permissionType: "book", instructorControlled: "", batchId: -1, title: "PR book", …}]    
var myItem=myData.find(item=>item.id===655);
console.log(myItem);
```

Comment: This does not make sense.. The item variable is only in the scope of the .find function

Comment: Sorry it will be myItem

Comment: This is not going to filter out items that are not books and have the same id. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myId = 643; // Some id you want to select by
var myData =
[
{id: 655, permissionType: "book", instructorControlled: "", batchId: -1, title: "PAckagebook1"},

{id: 643, permissionType: "book", instructorControlled: "", batchId: -1, title: "PR book"}
] 

let book = myData.find(obj => obj.permissionType === "book" && obj.id === myId)

console.log(book)
```